# Can Front and Back cameras of the same device have different supported hardware level?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

To get supported hardware level of the camera device we can use those methods of `Camera2` API, it requires `CAMERA_ID` to get this info.

Does it mean that each camera of the smartphone can has different hardware level? Or is it guaranteed that all cameras have the same hardware level and I can use any `CAMERA_ID` (front or back) of availables camera ids (`manager.cameraIdList`)?

```
val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CAMERA_ID)
val level = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every camera device has its own supported hardware level. There's no guarantee the front and back cameras support the same features, so you need to check them all individually.